# Cannot input data on textbox in Livewire because it resets automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, crud, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to make an update function in Laravel Livewire, but whenever I input data on the textbox, the inputted data reset to the data in my database. Still, I want to get new data and update the data on the database. I've tried changing the `wire:model` in the blade.php, and it receives a new input, but the data cannot be seen in the textbox before the change. Thank you

**View/Blade**

```
<div class="mt-4">
     <x-jet-label for="first_name" value="{{ __('first name') }}" />
     <x-jet-input id="first_name" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" 
         wire:model.debounce.800ms="first_name" required autofocus /> 
 </div>
 <x-jet-secondary-button class="ml-2" wire:click="update">
    {{ __('Update User') }}
 </x-jet-secondary-button>
```

**Controller**

```
public function getUserDataFromDatabase()
{
    $this->data = User::find($this->userId);
    $this->first_name = $this->data->first_name;
}
public function modelUpdateUser()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => $this->first_name,
    ];
}

public function update()
{
    User::find($this->userId)->update($this->modelUpdateUser());
    $this->resetValidation();
    $this->reset();
}
```

Comment: Which action triggers this function of `getUserDataFromDatabase()`?

Comment: it gets the data of the selected user from the database then automatically inputs it on the textbox so the user doesn't need another input for the textbox that they don't want any changes